# S3 site in Cloudfront Preflight 302 Error

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cors

I have a static s3 website hosted through CloudFront. In it, I make a request that will result in a redirect if the user is not logged in. Preflight then fails because of a 302:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://saml-provided.not.real' (redirected from 'https://my-site.not.real') from origin 'https://my-cloudfront.not.real' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

I setup my CORS in s3 to allow all origins:
[image: cors s3 setup]

And following [some](https://serverfault.com/questions/1146858/why-is-cloudfront-failing-to-pass-a-header-from-the-origin-to-the-client) [other](https://serverfault.com/questions/977818/cloudfront-drops-access-control-expose-headers-header-when-accept-encoding-is-se) [threads](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error#:%7E:text=To%20avoid%20the%20error%20%22No,distribution%20forwards%20the%20appropriate%20headers) setup my CloudFront like so:
[image: cloudfront]
[image: cache policy]

I have ran invalidations to no end, yet I cannot seem to get the headers to allow all hosts, they only allow my CloudFront origin:
[image: response headers]

Comment: It isn't clear why you appear to believe that this is related to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, when the problem appears to be that you shouldn't expect CORS to work when the target site is redirecting you elsewhere: *"Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request."*   Redirects are never allowed in response to a preflight request, and there is not anything you can change to allow them.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot if I proxy the request through a local ngrok instance with ```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: process.env.CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN || '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
};
``` then it works, leading me to believe it's the s3/cloudfront conf not taking the configuration properly

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here which would likely help you answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168773/how-to-resolve-preflight-is-invalid-redirect-or-redirect-is-not-allowed-for

You want to ensure that when your browser is making a cors pre-flight request that the response comes back with a 200.  If the server tries to redirect for any reason when the preflight request is sent, then you will get an error, which is enforced by your browser.

Your error message says: 'https://saml-provided.not.real' (redirected from 'https://my-site.not.real')

I would recommend using CURL to construct a preflight request to see how the server responds when you make the request.  If you get back a 3xx status code, follow that thread.

However, this is typically only an issue when attempting to use fetch api, or the older XMLHttpRequest api from within a web app.  Since your error message says that SAML is somehow involved I would also look in to why you are trying to do a saml authentication using something other than plain old HTTP posts from <form> elements which do not do preflight requests.